# Modifying Nginx configuration on Google Cloud App Engine Flexible Environment with Custom Runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

The Nginx load balancer of Google Cloud App Engine Flexible Environment (with custom runtime) logs remote IP addresses etc. to its access logs. What if I wanted to disable that behavior? Is it possible in any way? Docs don't say anything about configuring Nginx by yourself. Haven't find anything from the console either.

Comment: BTW, is there any specific reason why you would want to disable IP logging?

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable any IP logging, you have to disable the Google Cloud Load Balancer logs and also any logging done by NGINX.

In order to disable the ones done by the Load Balancer of Google Cloud, this page of their official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions) explains how to do it. You would need select "Disable log source" from the cloud HTTP Load Balancer.

On the other hand, to configure NGINX, apparently the only way to do so is modifying the nginx.conf file.

Because this you are using App Engine Flex and it's not possible to access these virtual machines/containers once the App had been deployed, you would need make sure to change the configuration before executing the deployment.

I've found a Serverfault [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/318574/how-to-disable-nginx-logging) which does explain how to disable NGINX logging, and another article which does explain the [NGINX configurations](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx/) with better depth in case they might be of use for you.

Comment: Where should I place the `nginx.conf`? Does App Engine read it from the project root?

Comment: You must set it in the same directory as the app.yaml file. There is an example in this github [page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-custom-runtimes-samples/tree/master/nginx)

Comment: @Masza If the answer has solved your doubts, please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this won't be possible. As per this [Logging docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging#appengine-vms) page:

> The App Engine flexible environment produces the following logs:
>
> - **Request logs** record requests sent to all App Engine apps. The request
>     log is provided by default and you cannot opt out of receiving it.
> - **App logs** record activity by software within the App Engine app. The
>     log is provided by default and you cannot opt out of receiving it.
> - **Runtime logs** are provided from the flexible environment using a
>     preinstalled Logging agent.